# Azure Cloud Service remote desktop is not working

Tags: rdp, azure-cloud-services

I have used Azure Cloud Services in the past and enabled RDP when I needed access to the machine for some troubleshooting. Today I needed access again, but I cannot access any cloud service anymore. I enabled RDP with my normal certificate and the same user and password as always, but I just cannot connect.

Adding the RDP connection works fine, but when logging in it just times out. It feels like a port that is blocked. Anyone knows if something has changed?

Comment: did the suggested solution help?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT It didn't work for two days and magically it did work again after two days.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks similar to the thread posted here.
[Azure classic cloud service cannot RDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512407/azure-classic-cloud-service-cannot-rdp)

Here is a document on enabling remote desktop connection for a role in Azure cloud services:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop-new-portal

Comment: @Ramon de Klein Did that help?